# Multiple tasks inside an Async class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to perform two different functions inside the AsyncTask class:- 1) Fetching String data from server. 2) Download Images from server . Please suggest me how can I make them run both . I tried to do it as follow but that does not work .

```
class SignIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {

            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                  }


            protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Bitmap...urls) 
                {
              }
```

Comment: you can use two diffrent async task one will get data from server and other will download image both are run parallel..

Comment: run both method in common doInBackgroud, don't use separate.

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya thanks for your answer but I need to store the data from both the classes into single table in SQLite.

Comment: @user3547558 you can store data in single table from many class..

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya currently My implementation for storing the data in the SQLite is inside AsyncTask class .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since your doInBackground() code will always stay the same, I recommend you move it into a general utility class.

Beyond that, you can go one of two ways:

```
1) Create a new AsyncTask for each type of request that can call your utility class, and have its own onPostExecute()

2) Create one AsyncTask that has a flag in it, which can be checked in the onPostExecute() method to see what code needs to be executed there. You will have to pass the flag in in the constructor or as a parameter in execute.
```